# CoreData relationship fault?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an Order which has a "to-many" relationship with Units. When I try to log the units (NSSet) in Order, I get a fault error:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Order" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:mainContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [mainContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                     error:nil];
for (Order *order in fetchedObjects) {

    NSLog(@"%@", [order units]);
    break;
}        
[fetchRequest release];
```

results in:

```
Relationship 'units' fault on managed object (0x6d9dd00) <Order: 0x6d9dd00> (entity: Order; id: 0x6d88e40 <x-coredata://97A3F3D5-ABA7-499A-A460-5E25CF49C528/Order/p1> ; data: {
    composition = Hemlock;
    condition = "";
    consignee = "";
    consigneeCompanyName = "";
    contactAlternatePhone = "";
    contactEmail = "";
    contactFirstName = "";
    contactLastName = "";
    contactPhone = "";
    customer = "Havard Empire";
    customerCompanyName = "";
    customerNotes = "";
    dateDue = "1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    dateEntered = "1/6/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    dateOrdered = "1/6/2012 12:00:00 AM";
    deliveryAddress1 = "";
    deliveryAddress2 = "";
    deliveryCity = "";
    deliverySpecialInstructions = "";
    deliveryState = "";
    deliveryZip = "";
    depth = 01;
    detail = "";
    freightRate = "";
    grade = Cull;
    instructionsDirectionsNotes = "";
    lastUpdated = "1/6/2012 3:00:43 PM";
    length = 01;
    location = "Lucedale, ms";
    matsPerLoad = "";
    memoLineNotes = "";
    notes = "";
    orderID = 201205134922479;
    orderNumber = 01062012;
    pUP = Cable;
    pricePerItem = "";
    purchaseOrderNumber = "";
    pushToQuickBooks = True;
    quantity = 0;
    quickbooksCompany = 1;
    salesman = "Accounting Adj";
    separateRate = False;
    taxRate = "";
    totalLoads = "";
    type = "2ply Mat";
    units = "<relationship fault: 0x6dacf20 'units'>";
    vendorID = 10;
    width = 01;
})
```

The units aren't printed. It says `"<relationship fault: 0x6dacf20 'units'>";`

Also, why is it printing the entire object when I only want units?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This isn't an error - it is a feature of Core Data called 'faulting'. Here is Apple's [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html):

> Faulting reduces the amount of memory your application consumes. A
>   fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that
>   has not yet been fully realized, or a collection object that
>   represents a relationship:
>
> A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but
>   its persistent variables are not yet initialized. A relationship fault
>   is a subclass of the collection class that represents the
>   relationship. Faulting allows Core Data to put boundaries on the
>   object graph. Because a fault is not realized, a managed object fault
>   consumes less memory, and managed objects related to a fault are not
>   required to be represented in memory at all.

If you want to see each Unit object then you will have to specifically access them. Try the following:

```
for (Order *order in fetchedObjects) {
    for (Unit *unit in [order units]) {
       NSLog(@"%@", unit);
       //I am not at a computer, so I cannot test, but this should work. You might have to access each property of the unit object to fire the fault, but I don't believe that is necessary.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. I tried this before.

Comment: Nothing. it doesn't iterate through the 2nd loop. I check the count and it returns zero.

Comment: Yea. But nvm, I found out the problem. You were right. Thanks!

Comment: @0xSina I have the same problem. my count return 0. How did you solve this?

Comment: @0xSina Can you please share with us.. how did you managed to solve this error I am also facing this issue

Comment: What's missing from the code is that you should access one of the attributes of the entity, e.g. NSLog(@"%@", unit.unitDescription), and then the fault be turned into an object.

Comment: Also, you could call the `allObjects` method of the relationship property to print them with out having to iterate them and access any of their attributes.

Comment: Fault sounds like someone chose a bad placeholder word for the word placeholder.

Comment: I agree fault does sound like bad a misleading word here but I believe the term fault comes from the concept of page faults. When you look at it from that stand point, I think it makes sense. Apple actually has good documentation on this. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH18-SW1

Answer (score 12):

In order to **see all the objects of a *"to-many"* relationship**, you can call it with the **`allObjects`** method of the relationship's `NSSet`.

In your specific case, the code to print all the *Units* of the first *Order* in `fetchedObjects` would be like this:

```
for (Order *order in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [order.units allObjects]);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift it would go like so:

```
for order in fetchedObjects {
    for unit in order.units.allObjects as [Unit] {
        println(unit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep, I had also the same problem.
Try just print some field of this table, in example:

```
    for(Category *category in fetchedObjects) 
    {
        for(Cards *card in category.cards) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Question %@", card.question);
            NSLog(@"Card %@", card);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very counter intuitive. I scratched my head for about a whole day until I realised that I cannot print out the whole NSSet object or each NSManagedObject in the set like so :

```
for (Order *order in fetchedObjects) {
   for (Unit *unit in [order units]) {
      NSLog(@"%@", unit);
   }
}
```

This will generate fault in xcode .. But If I print out each attribute in each NSMangedObject, it is fine. I guess Apple has memory concern over Auto-loading to-many objects. In a scenario where there is a chain of to-many relationships, it will consume a lot of memory. So need to lazy-load each attribute.

```
for (Order *order in fetchedObjects) {
   for (Unit *unit in [order units]) {
      NSLog(@"Unit Name : %@", unit.name);
   }
}
```

That will print out the unit name..