# relationship fault (core data)

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, fault

I am new to core data and I need help with the following problem:

I have two entities: Talk and Speaker. They have a to many relationship.

Talk - destination: Speaker , inverse: talk
Speaker - destination: Talk, inverse: speaker

The field "To-Many Relationship" is checked on both entities.

I have a table view controller to list all talks available. This is how am i doing:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Talk" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

When i click on a cell, i want to load another view controller, showing only the details of the selected talk.

This is what i am doing:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TalksDetailsViewController *talksDetails = [[TalksDetailsViewController alloc] initWithTalksInfo:[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:talksDetails animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is: i can't see the speakers on TalksDetailsViewController. This is the info sent to TalksDetailsViewController:

```
Info: <Talk: 0x6e66920> (entity: Talk; id: 0x6e66880 <x-coredata://4063FE84-E6DB-4588-8133-9A55B512D6C8/Talk/p2> ; data: {
    date = "2012-08-31 03:00:00 +0000";
    id = 7;
    speaker = "<relationship fault: 0x6e994e0 'speaker'>";
    "start_time" = "17:14:55";
})
```

I tried something as the code below, but it did not worked:

```
for (Speaker *speakerInfo in self.talkInfo.speaker) {
        NSLog(@"speaker info: %@", speakerInfo);
}
```

It never gets into the for.

If i try to log self.talkInfo.speaker i get something like:

```
Relationship 'speaker' fault on managed object (0x7a76c30) <Talk: 0x7a76c30> (entity: Talk; id: 0x7a76b90 <x-coredata://4063FE84-E6DB-4588-8133-9A55B512D6C8/Talk/p2> ; data: {
    date = "2012-08-31 03:00:00 +0000";
    id = 7;
    speaker = "<relationship fault: 0x6bc5990 'speaker'>";
    "start_time" = "17:14:55";
})
```

I saw some similar questions, but could not fix my problem.

Any tips?

Comment: Relationship Fault does not mean an error, have you tried logging an attribute from speaker? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8876336/879119

Comment: Tried, but did not worked. Could not fix my problem based on the answer you pointed out. But thanks.

Comment: Can you log the self.talkInfo? So I can see how that's structured

Comment: Here it is:

Info: <Talk: 0x6e66920> (entity: Talk; id: 0x6e66880 <x-coredata://4063FE84-E6DB-4588-8133-9A55B512D6C8/Talk/p2> ; data: {
    date = "2012-08-31 03:00:00 +0000";
    id = 7;
    speaker = "<relationship fault: 0x6e994e0 'speaker'>";
    "start_time" = "17:14:55";
})

Comment: So is it a one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 1):

First examine the Objects with a SQLite Browser ([here if you dont have one](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser)). And make sure that the data is being stored in core data. Access the simulator file at `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/XX/Applications/XXXXXXXXXXX/Documents/XXXX.sqlite`. Make sure that the `ZTALKS` **table** has a **column** `ZSPEAKER` and a value for it, this should correspond to the `Z_PK` value in the `ZSPEAKER` **table**. If it does the relationships are connected.

Your model should look something like this:

[image]

When you have a Talk object like so:

```
 Talk *talk = [**YourManagedObjectContext**  executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

You should be able to grab it's speaker like so:

```
Speaker *speaker = talk.speaker;
```

I understand this is a little different from your setup but hopefully this should help.

Comment: There's no column ZSPEAKER on ZTALKS. This column is create when i do not set a many to many relationship. When i set, the column is not created.

All the information comes from an JSON, in this format:
            "date": "2012-11-02",
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Java",
            "speaker": [
                "/api/v1/speaker/1/",
                "/api/v1/speaker/2/"
            ],


How i save the array:

if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSSet *valueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:value];
            [managedObject setValue:valueSet forKey:key];
        }