# coredata NSFetchRequest one to many relationship Relationship fault on managed object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have a coredata project with the following entities:

I'm trying to get the list of the content base on the category:

here is my coredata clasess .h:

```
@interface Content : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contenido;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * index;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * titulo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uploadCloudKit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Categories *category;

---

@class Content;

@interface Categories : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * categoryName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *content;
@end



NSEntityDescription *categoryDescription = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSFetchRequest *categoRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
categoRequest.entity = categoryDescription;
NSPredicate *categoPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryName like %@", category];
categoRequest.predicate = categoPredicate;
 NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:categoRequest error:&error];
```

but when I try to access the content on the result for the category I get:

```
po [results valueForKey:@"content"]
<__NSArrayI 0x6080000243a0>(
Relationship 'content' fault on managed object (0x6080000a2220) <Categories: 0x6080000a2220> (entity: Categories; id: 0x40002b <x-coredata://FDBA3FB2-F1F8-498E-9071-3A5D1ABE66F0/Categories/p1> ; data: {
    categoryName = movies;
    content = "<relationship fault: 0x610000030fa0 'content'>";
})
)
```

Any of you knows how can I get the content items of the result?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: This is not an error, it is expected behaviour: see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8876234/3985749).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a normal behaviour for CoreData. You should read [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html). There you can read about fault objects for CoreData. In two words - fault means that CoreData has this object but know (for some reason CoreData won't print you all fields of the object).
In order to see all vields you should do this:

```
[categoRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

But I recomend you to do this only for debug, because CoreData smarter and know what to do with memory managment)