# Retrieve data from a one to many relationship core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many

I need to retrieve the values of each attribute in a to many relationship. My code to load it is

```
func loadData() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Company")

    do {
        //Get the results
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        //Load the results in the people array
        people = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        for i in 0..<people.count {
            let data = people[i]
            let variableToPrint = data.valueForKey("employee")
            print(variableToPrint)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

If I do that, it returns:

> Optional(Relationship 'employee' fault on managed object
>   (0x7f93f363dd80)  (entity: Company;
>   id: 0xd000000000080000
>    ; data:
>   {
>       employee = "";
>       name = Apple; }))

My code to save to core data is

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Company", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
let company = NSManagedObject(entity: companyEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    company.setValue("Apple", forKey: "name")

//Add employees
let employeeEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employees", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

let person = NSManagedObject(entity: employeeEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
for i in 0..<employeeNameArray.count {
        let name = employeeNameArray[i]
        let when = dateJoinedArray[i]
        let number = employeeNumberArray[i]

        person.setValue(name, forKey: "employeeName")
        person.setValue(number, forKey: "employeeNumber")
        person.setValue(when, forKey: "dateHired")
        company.setValue(NSSet(object: person), forKey: "employee")
}

//Employee info to company        
company.setValue(NSSet(object: person), forKey: "employee")

do {
    try managedContext.save()
    //people.append(person)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

My core data setup has 2 entities. One called Company and one called Employees.
Company has a name attribute, and an employee relationship with a destination of Employees, and is to many.

In employees, I have `dateHired, employeeName, and employeeNumber attributes, and in relationships, I have a relationship called company with the destination Company, and is a to one type.

I need to be able to load all of the Employees attributes at the same time as the Company attributes as they are tied together.

Comment: You can simply use company.employees, that's a NSSet created by Core Data itself, no need to do a fetch request on company and the employees.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Are there any records being returned? 
Also the message that you are getting is not an error. Check this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault

Comment: Not clear what your problem actually is...

Comment: Don't be concerned by the "Relationship 'employee' fault" - it is perfectly normal - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8876336/3985749).

Comment: Ok, thanks! How would I be able to retrieve only one attribute from the employees entity which is connected to Company?

Comment: @someonecalledphilippe To get a set holding all the values of (for example) the "name" attribute of the `employee` relationship, just use `let variableToPrint = data.valueForKeyPath("employee.name")`