# accessing contents of a relationship fault in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, core-data

I'm debugging an error that involves Core Data and am having trouble viewing the contents of the information retrieved.  For example, when entering "po localSchedules" in the Xcode debugger console, this is what I get:

```
<Schedules: 0x1702c6d60> (entity: Schedules; id: 0xd000000000340008 <x-coredata://D32DD2B0-A69F-45B4-9856-7D935B41718D/Schedules/p13> ; data: {
    accessorySchedule = "<relationship fault: 0x1700362a0 'accessorySchedule'>";
    name = "TEST";
})
```

How can I view the contents of `accessorySchedule`?  `"<relationship fault: 0x1700362a0 'accessorySchedule'>"` is not very informative.  Here's some relevant code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSArray *localSchedules = [self fetchLocalSchedulesInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext error:&fetchError];
```

Using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault), I implemented the following:

```
for (Schedules *schedule in localSchedules) {
    for (AccessorySchedule *accessorySchedule in [schedule accessorySchedule]) {
        NSLog(@"RESULT - %@", accessorySchedule);
    }
}
```

But, the result was also not informative:

```
RESULT - <AccessorySchedule: 0x1740b6da0> (entity: AccessorySchedule; id: 0xd00000000040000a <x-coredata://D32DD2B0-A69F-45B4-9856-7D935B41718D/AccessorySchedule/p16> ; data: <fault>)
```

In the above, how can I see what's stored in `data: <fault>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreData relationship fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault)

Comment: I saw that post but the solutions posted didn't show me any additional info about the contents of `accessorySchedule`.  Updated my question to provide more info based on that post.

Comment: Just access any attribute of the AccessorySchedule.  CoreData will then fire the fault. If you then repeat the same NSLog, it will show all the attributes of the AccessorySchedule.

Answer (score 0):

I don't no this one is help full for u r issue 
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO] We have to set request  is to carring the objects we have to decode that .hope this will help you .