# Relationship fault upon reopening app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

When I run the application first time and add data everything is fine relationship are being created and no error. If I stop and run it again (same data using core data) the xcode console within the relationship of entities says relationship fault.

Has anyone experienced this before if so how did you resolve it?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault) it may help to understand fault concept.

Answer (score 0):

To access the objects I used the following although helpful link is provided with the comment section of the question.

```
    for item in day.dayExercises{
        print(item)
    }
```