# How to loop through a relationship in Swift 4

Tags: swift, core-data

Let's say that I have an array 'Stores' which contains Store entities from a Core Data database.

The user of the app wants to see all products of store 1 and 4, so he selects 'store 1' and 'store 4' in the tableview.

How can I now put all the products from store 1 and store 4 in an array?

```
for store in selectedStores {
    let products = store.products
    print(store.name) // line3
    print(store.products) // line4
    for product in products! {
        print("\(product)") // line6
    }
}
```

> Line 3 prints:

```
Optional("Store 1")
```

> Line 4 prints:

```
Optional(Relationship 'products' fault on managed object (0x1c0097610) <__App.Store: 0x1c0097610> (entity: Store; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://8777A8A9-3416-4525-9246-509B9070D222/Store/p1> ; data: {
    name = Store 1;
    products = "<relationship fault: 0x1c02283a0 'products'>";
}))
```

> Line 6 prints:

```
<__App.Product: 0x1c4090040> (entity: Product; id: 0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://8777A8A9-3416-4525-9246-509B9070D222/Product/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

My datastructure:

```
"Store"
attributes: "name"
relationships: "products"

"Product"
attributes: "name", "price"
relationships: "stores"
```

== Edit ==

```
var selectedStores: [Store] = []

fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Store> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Store> = Store()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Comment: Where is the array you are trying to form? I don't see any array anywhere in your code. But in any case nothing is going to happen until you fetch the products. Right now, they are faulting. You should not be looping; you should construct a fetch that gets the products for all selected stores.

Comment: I have added the code you asked for. But I have also found a solution myself (see the answer below). Though, you mention that I should not forloop through these relationships, why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution where I was looking for here: [CoreData relationship fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault)

I had to change:

```
for store in selectedStores {
    let products = store.products
    print(store.name) // line3
    print(store.products) // line4
    for product in products! {
        print("\(product)") // line6
    }
}
```

to

```
for store in selectedStores {
    for product in store.products?.allObjects as! [Product] {
        print(product.name!)
    }
}
```