# Swift: Core Data fetch request to Core Data Entity array

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to fetch some values out of a CoreData store, typed as an array of the generated CoreData Entity classes. Is this possible?

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let responseFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Response")

do {
    var responses = try managedContext.fetch(responseFetchRequest) as! [Response]
    print(responses[0])
} catch {
    print("Failed!")
}
```

This print statement is only printing the following to console:

[image: Printed entity object]

Is it wrong to use these entity classes as such? I've used them before for creating data (see usage below), so surely you can use them as models too?

```
let responseEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Response", in: managedContext)!
let response = Response(
    context: NSManagedObject(
        entity: responseEntity,
        insertInto: managedContext
    ).managedObjectContext!
)
```

Also, for context, this is what I mean by a CoreData entity:

[image: CoreData entity]

Comment: Your approach is fine. If you are concerned by the "relationship fault", please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8876234/3985749) and the various answers.

Comment: @pbasdf Ahh great, thanks for the tip. My main concern is that the data is coming back as `nil` though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think your problem lies in the code where you create the objects:

```
let responseEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Response", in: managedContext)!
let response = Response(
    context: NSManagedObject(
        entity: responseEntity,
        insertInto: managedContext
    ).managedObjectContext!
)
```

You are passing `NSManagedObject(entity: responseEntity, insertInto: managedContext).managedObjectContext!` into the `context` parameter of the initialiser.  What that snippet does is to create a blank object, inserts it into `managedContext`, and then gets its `managedObjectContext` property.  This happens before the `Response` object is initialised, so you are creating TWO objects with every call.  Try changing to:

```
let response = Response(context: managedContext)
```

CoreData will infer the correct entity based on the class.