# Swift - Fetching relational data from an object?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to figure out how to access the relationship data from an object. I have an object passed in from the previous view, into a detailVC.

```
var selectedRecipe: Recipe?
```

And I'm then trying to access the recipes photos. `@NSManaged public var recipeImage: NSSet?` Which is a `to many` relation to `RecipeImage`. Which contains `imageData: Data` (The reverse is a `to-one` relationship).

Previously I was creating and matching a UUID between the objects. But I don't think thats need and theres likely a better way?

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<RecipeImage> = RecipeImage.fetchRequest()
if let identifier = selectedRecipe?.id {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "selectedRecipe.id == %@", identifier as CVarArg)
request.predicate = predicate
}
    

etc...
```

So basically, how can I fetch with a predicate of the object I want to search its relational data on?

---

EDIT:

It seems it's as simple as this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "myRelationship == %@", selectedRecipe as CVarArg)
```

Comment: If you have a relationship defined between them then you also have a property on each with the name of the relationship that you can use to access the other entity object(s). So `let images = selectedRecipe.recipeImage` should give you all the images without the need to do execute a fetch request-

Comment: That works, but it faults.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you update the relationship properties properly using `addToRecipeImage`?

Comment: It's entirely possible i'm doing something wrong. However, heres `print(images)` using `let images = selectedRecipe.recipeImage`: `Relationship 'recipeImage' fault on managed object (0x600002b54ff0)` - Edit - Is faulting bad?

Comment: Faulting is perfectly normal - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876336/3985749)

Comment: Thank you. So theres no issue / only a minor performance cost? if any?