# Access data in Core Data using relationships and predicate

Tags: swift, relationship

I am using Core data to store two databases that contain a relationships.
There is a logbook database and a IFRApproaches database.

A logbook entry can have multiple approaches.
An approach can only be linked to one logbook entry.

Attached is screenshots of my data model and relationships.
[image: Data Model]
[image: Relationship 1]
[image: Relationship 2]

When the "submit" button is pressed this is the code to save the entry to the logbook, and the approaches as well..  I need the approaches (how ever many) associated with a singular entry.  My question is How I can use a predicate to query the database at a later time for all the approaches associated with a various entry.

```
lazy var newEntry = Logbook(context: LoadData.shared.context)
        if errorCount == 0 {
            
            if modifyEntry == false {
                if entryHolding.date == nil {
                    newEntry.date = Date()
                } else {
                    newEntry.date = entryHolding.date
                    
                }
                newEntry.aircraftID = entryHolding.aircraftID
                
                
                
                
                newEntry.aircraftSelect = LoadData.shared.aircraftArray[aircraftArrayIndexPath!.row]
                newEntry.categoryAndClass = newEntry.aircraftSelect?.categoryAndClass
                newEntry.typeCode = entryHolding.typeCode
                newEntry.from = entryHolding.from
                newEntry.to = entryHolding.to
                newEntry.route = entryHolding.route
                newEntry.totalTime = entryHolding.totalTime
                newEntry.pic = entryHolding.PIC
                newEntry.sic = entryHolding.SIC
                newEntry.solo = entryHolding.solo
                newEntry.dual = entryHolding.dual
                newEntry.crossCountry = entryHolding.crossCountry
                newEntry.night = entryHolding.night
                newEntry.simInstrument = entryHolding.simInstrument
                newEntry.actualInstrument = entryHolding.actualInstrument
                newEntry.hold = Int16(entryHolding.hold)
                newEntry.dayLanding = Int16(entryHolding.dayLanding)
                newEntry.nightLanding = Int16(entryHolding.nightLanding)
                newEntry.bfr = entryHolding.BFR
                newEntry.checkride = entryHolding.checkRide
                newEntry.ipc = entryHolding.IPC
                newEntry.comments = entryHolding.comments
                
                
                
                for i in 0..<approach.count {
                    var newApproach = IFRApproaches(context: LoadData.shared.context)
                    newApproach.airport = approach[i].airportID
                    newApproach.typeOfApproach = approach[i].type
                    newApproach.runway = approach[i].runwayNum
                    //newApproach.entry = newEntry
                    newEntry.addToApproaches(newApproach)
                    LoadData.shared.approachArray.append(newApproach)
                    
                }
                
                
                
                LoadData.shared.entryArray.append(newEntry)
                LoadData.shared.saveData()
```

Comment: "...associated with a various entry", not sure I understand this correctly but if you want to get the approaches for a LogBook object you should know that the relationships you have created also are properties on the generated classes. So for instance `let approaches = myLogBook.approaches`

Comment: Let me to try to explain better.  A user can create a logbook entry that is saved into the Logbook database.  Within an entry, a user can add an “approach”.  The user can any amount of approaches.  In the code `//newApproach.entry = newEntry
                    newEntry.addToApproaches(newApproach) ` i am trying to relate the approach and the logbook entry (not sure if i did this correct, or which line to use). I must find a way to make a predicate to query the database so at a later time if a user views a logbook entry, the predicate will display all approaches associated with the entry.

Comment: And my previous comment tells you that you do not need such predicate, you can access the approaches directly via the logbook object (or entry if you will) directly

Comment: Does it matter which way i set the relationship? I think i only need one of these lines? `//newApproach.entry = newEntry                     //newEntry.addToApproaches(newApproach) `

Comment: Yes only one of them is needed

Comment: I tried accessing the data like you instructed. I used this code when loading up an entry..          `print(LoadData.shared.entryArray[entryNumber!].approaches)`. This prints in the console ... ptional(Relationship 'approaches' fault on managed object (0x600001e16fd0) <joshLogbook.Logbook: 0x600001e16fd0>

Comment: This is perfectly normal, relationships objects are not loaded until they are accessed (this is what 'fault' refers to), see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault) for instance. So instead of printing like that you should try to access them using `allObjects` or create an array instead